# Combine multiple SQL columns into a single column of an HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to combine data from multiple columns in a MySQL table into a single column in an HTML table, where each record will be a new row in the HTML table?

In this example, a table in MySQL has two columns (Col1, Col2). The data from Col1 is displayed in the first column in the HTML table. The data from Col2 in MySQL is displayed in the second column in the HTML table. In another words, the HTML table matches the layout of the MySQL table.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = "select * from table1";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
  $col1 = $row['col1'];
  $col2 = $row['col2'];

  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> $col1 </td>";
  echo "<td> $col2 </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

MySQL Table:

```
| - - - - | - - - - - - - |
| Col1    |    Col2       |
| - - - - | - - - - - - - |
| Blue    |    Car        |
| Green   |    Truck      |
| Yellow  |    Van        |
| - - - - | - - - - - - - |
```

HTML Table:

```
| - - - - | - - - - - - - |
| Column1 |    Column2    |
| - - - - | - - - - - - - |
| Blue    |    Car        |
| Green   |    Truck      |
| Yellow  |    Van        |
| - - - - | - - - - - - - |
```

If $col1 and $col2 are put inside of a single TD tag, this does get both $col1 and $col2 to display in Col1 in the HTML table. However, both $col1 and $col2 are displayed in the same cell.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = "select * from table1";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
  $col1 = $row['col1'];
  $col2 = $row['col2'];

  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> $col1 $col2 </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

HTML Table:

```
| - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| Column1                 |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| Blue Car                |
| Green Truck             |
| Yellow Van              |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - |
```

Is it possible to echo $Col1 and $Col2 in Column1 of the HTML table and have each record be in its own row in the HTML table?

```
| - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| Column1                 |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| Blue                    |
| Green                   |
| Yellow                  |
| Car                     |
| Truck                   |
| Van                     |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - |
```

Comment: You want the result like the last figure in your question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to have two loops. It can be done in single loop. Separate the col1 and col2 values in different variables. and at the end print it.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = "select * from table1";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$str = "<table>";
$str_col2 = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
  $col1 = $row['col1'];
  $col2 = $row['col2'];    

  $str .= "<tr><td> $col1 </td></tr>";
  $str_col2 .= "<tr><td> $col2 </td></tr>";
}
echo $str . $str_col2 . "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much for the solution Aju!

Comment: Glad to hear...!! Thanks :)

Comment: Are you talking about the scenario when result is empty from DB?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is valid, but not correct. This is might be the structure of your resultant table.

Make a new array where you store the `col2` value for showing after all the `col1` value. After completing the `col1` value loop again for the second `col2` values for the display.

```
$col2 = array();
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
  $col1 = $row['col1'];
  $col2[] = $row['col2'];

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> $col1 </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
for($i = 0; $ < count($col2); $i++){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> $col2[$i] </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is a fascinating solution. I had not considered adding a "for" loop after the "while" loop. I am going to experiment with this. This actually is going to also be useful for the scenario I am working on, as I actually simplified this issue to make the issue easier to digest :)

Comment: yes, @AjuJohn has the good answer for this question, you must go with him.